# Send json and file with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I used to send POST request to server with **Retrofit2**:

```
    @POST("goals")
    Call<Void> postGoal(@Body Goal goal);
```

where Goal was object with some String/Integer fields.

Now I need to add a photo file there.
I know I need to **switch** to use **Multipart**:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("goals")
    Call<Void> postGoal(
            @Part("picture") RequestBody picture
            );

//...
//Instantaining picture 
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), path)
```

But how am I supposed to add previous fields ? In particular is there a way to add whole Goal object without dividing it for fields ?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sending json and file you can follow something like this.

```
@Multipart
@POST("goals")
Call<JsonModel> postGoal(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("json") RequestBody json);
```

Now convert your Object which you want to send as a json into json using Gson.
like this.

```
    String json = new Gson().toJson(new Goal());

  File file = new File(path);
                        RequestBody requestFile =
                                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

                        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                        MultipartBody.Part body =
                                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

                        // add another part within the multipart request
                        RequestBody jsonBody=
                                RequestBody.create(
                                        MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), json);
                        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(url)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();
                        RestApi api = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
                        Call<ResponseBody> call = api.upload(jsonBody, body);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                                Log.d("onResponse: ", "success");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.d("onFailure: ", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@Part` with you goal like this

```
@Multipart
    @POST("goals")
    Call<Void> postGoal(
            @Part("picture") RequestBody picture,
            @Part("goal") RequestBody goal
            );

    //...
    //Instantaining picture 
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), path)
```

You can find more details : [retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)